# Inner trait breaks implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

```
object Test {

  trait Foo

  trait TC[A]

  object TC {
    implicit def tc1[F <: Foo] = new TC[F] {}
    implicit def tc2[F1 <: Foo, F2 <: Foo] = new TC[(F1, F2)] {}
  }   

  object Bar {
    trait X
    val c = new Foo with X
    def bar[A](a: this.type => A)(implicit tc: TC[A]) = 1
  }

  Bar bar (_.c)

  Bar bar (b => (b.c, b.c))
}
```

The last line gives compiler error "could not find implicit value for parameter tc...".

Now: moving `trait X` outside of `object Bar` makes it work.

The next to last line works in both cases.

Is there any good reason for this, and/or is it possible to make it work without moving the trait out of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to be a full blown answer (and contains a high dose of speculation), but given that you got none until now I imagine that it's better than nothing.

It seems that the problem lies with the fact that the compiler treats `X` in `new Foo with X` as a path-dependant type, even though we are in an object definition rather than a class. 
Because of this, the compiler then infers `A = (Test.Foo with b.X, Test.Foo with b.X) forSome { val b: Test.Bar.type }` in the second call to `bar`. 
This requires the compiler to find an implicit value of type `TC[(Test.Foo with b.X, Test.Foo with b.X) forSome { val b: Test.Bar.type }]`, and apparently `tc2` is no fit (I am not intimate enough with the corner cases fo the scala type system to know for sure if there is a genuine incompatibility, or if the compiler just has no clue)

[speculation mode]

The problem with the path-dependent type handling smells like a bug to me (or at least an underspecified oddity). I think that the culprit is that the body of an object is compiled no different from a class, and **then** is somehow made into a singleton object, which means that `new Foo with X` is really seen as `new Foo with this.X` instead of `new Foo with Bar.X`, and thus treated as a path dependent type (even though they should IMHO denote the very same thing in this case).

[/speculation mode]

And now for the weird part (which is also the work around that you requested): turning this:

```
val c = new Foo with X
```

into this:

```
val c = new Foo with Bar.X
```

actually fixes the compilation. As I understand it, this is because by explicitly specifying `Bar` we force the compiler to recognize that `Bar.X` is a stable path, which clears the problem with path dependent types.

Now, the real work around is of course to really move `X` outside `Bar` as you suggested. It works and is painless, so why not do it?

Comment: Thanks, interesting speculation. To your last question, in my non-minimized version keeping the trait inside is crucial, unfortunately. :)